# Initialize to MongoCursor

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I need a `var` (`res` in the following) to accept the answer of a `find()`, i.e. `MongoCursor`, because I have to have access to my var inside `if`-conditions (see below).

Here is what I am doing:

```
var query = new MongoDBObject()
val res = ""

if ("condition_1" == field_1))
{
    query += "field" -> "t"

    if ("condition_2" == "field_2"))
    {
        res = collection.find(q).sort("basic_field" -> 1)
       }
    else if ("condition_2" == "field_2"))
    {
        res = collection.find(q).sort("important_field" -> -1).limit(101)
    }
}

//Perform some operations on res
```

How can I initialize my `res` to accept a `MongoCursor`?

`var res = MongoCursor` and `var res = DBCursor` do not function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res: MongoCursor = _
```

This assigns the default value to res (probably null).

But you should avoid using var wherever possible.
Because in scala if can return a result it's possible to directly assign the result to res, e.g.:

```
val res =  if ("condition_1" == field_1)) {
             query += "field" -> "t"
             if ("condition_2" == "field_2")) {
               collection.find(q).sort("basic_field" -> 1)
             } else if ("condition_2" == "field_2")) {
               collection.find(q).sort("important_field" -> -1).limit(101)
             }
           }
```

Comment: `var res: MongoCursor = _` did not work because: `local variables must be initialized`. So I used `null` and it worked. I will try what you advise once it works properly. Great thanks.